# I want that my expandable list View should have limited groups and it should not scroll. Only thing that should scroll is the child view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want that my expandable list View should pinned or can say sticky groups headers and it should not scroll. Only thing that should scroll is the child view inside the each groups how to do that in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can create such view manually by using textview for headers(parent) and different listview for each parent.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/qa_list_item_title"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Debriefing"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1490dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Qualification"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1560dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Forecasting"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1490dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Buying Phases"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1490dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sales Process"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1490dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Solution Development"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1490dp" >
        </ListView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sequence of Events"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1560dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Pipeline"
            android:textColor="@color/qa_list_background" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/qalist8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1490dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.